# Mockito 2 and junit 5 : mocking classes

Tags: mockito, junit5

I have a strange behaviour with mockito 2 and Junit 5 : Mockito can't mock a class.

I extracted my test to a simple test case :

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoJavaExtension.class)
class JavaTest {

    @Test
    void shouldMockClass(){
        final MockedJavaClass mock = mock(MockedJavaClass.class);
        when(mock.execute()).thenReturn(Collections.singletonList("some value"));

        assertEquals(1, mock.execute().size());
    }

    @Test
    void shouldMockInterface(){
        final MockedJavaInterface mock = mock(MockedJavaInterface.class);
        when(mock.execute()).thenReturn(Collections.singletonList("some value"));

        assertEquals(1, mock.execute().size());
    }

}

class MockedJavaClass{
    List<String> execute(){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}

interface MockedJavaInterface{
    default List<String> execute(){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

When I run this test, I get the IllegalArgumentException :

```
JUnit Jupiter:JavaTest:shouldMockClass()
  MethodSource [className = 'JavaTest', methodName = 'shouldMockClass', methodParameterTypes = '']
  => java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
     MockedJavaClass.execute(JavaTest.java:36)
     JavaTest.shouldMockClass(JavaTest.java:19)
```

It means that **the class is not mocked at all**.

I also tried with an external class (not an inner one), and the issue is still the same...

This is also my build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.1.1"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'

sourceCompatibility = 8
targetCompatibility = 8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.18.0"
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:2.18.0"


    testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.1.1")
    testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.1.1")
    testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.1.1")
    testRuntime("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.1.1")
}

junitPlatform {
    filters {
        engines {
            include 'junit-jupiter'
        }
        includeClassNamePattern '.*Test'
    }
}
```

I also tried with the mockito junit5 extension to inject mocks, but I still have the problem...

Any help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally ended finding the solution : My first test was a Kotlin one, in a "open class" but a non-opened method declaration.

Mockito **can't mock a method with a package access nor a final method** !

In this particular case, it just calls the real method when you try to mock it, without telling you anything...

Maybe this post will be useful for someone ! –

Comment: The mockito-inline extension seems to allow mocking also final methods (not only final classes).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mock the `execute` function on your `MockClass` so it used the implementation of `execute` that was in the class definition - in other words the `IllegalArgumentException`.

You need to setup your mocks such that they provide dummy implementations of the methods that are going to be required as dependancies to your test case. In this particular case it doesn't appear you are testing anything really, just learning Mockito?

So yea, the answer is - provide mock implementations or the default will be used.

Comment: Mockito in previous version returns emptyList when a defined mock can't found. I'm just looking to check if it's a difference with the new versions !

Comment: My test is simplified here to be clear, but actually you're right, we should defined mock here.